# How can translate the the whole screen language of application by only clicking single click on lang selection using python for flutter application

Tags: python, django, flutter, language-translation

I have a Flutter app with 100 language choice on login page. I want when user choose one language suppose "Hindi" language the language of whole application screen should change.  How can I change the language of whole application.

Comment: Yes you can but need to specify the the each and every string in your language json file.

Comment: You can use easy_localization package for your purpose

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.